# c# - check if string contains character and number

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

How do I check if a string contains the following characters "-A" followed by a number?

Ex: thisIsaString-A21  = yes, contains "-A" followed by a number

Ex: thisIsaNotherString-AB21 = no, does not contain "-A" followed by a number

Comment: What have you tried? since you already know it's called regex, finding an answer should take less than a minute.

Comment: How about `thisIsaString-A21B something else` is it ok?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It can be done with a regular expression:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"-A\d")) { ... }
```

The `\d` matches any digit.

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/w7hCW)

Comment: ...except `\d` will only match a single digit whereas the example given is `-A21`, so presumably the OP requires both digits

Comment: @AndrasZoltan: That's a relevant concern if you want to extract the number (as in your answer) but it's not relevant if you just want to test if there is a match.

Comment: If s = "C:\\", and Regex.IsMatch(s, @"-A\d") is false

Answer (score 4):

```
if(Regex.IsMatch("thisIsaString-A21", "-A\\d+"))
{
  //code to execute
}
```

If you actually want to extract the -A[num] bit then you can do this:

```
var m = Regex.Match("thisIsaString-A21", "-A\\d+"));
if(m.Success)
{
  Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
  //prints '-A21'
}
```

There are other things you can do - such as if you need to extract the A[num] bit on its own or just the number:

```
var m = Regex.Match("thisIsaString-A21", "(?<=-A)\\d+");
//now m.Groups[0].Value contains just '21'
```

Or as in my first suggestion, if you want the 'A21':

```
var m = Regex.Match("thisIsaString-A21", "(?<=-)A\\d+");
//now m.Groups[0].Value contains 'A21'
```

There are other ways to achieve these last two - I like the non-capturing group `(?<=)` because, as the name implies, it keeps the output groups clean.

Comment: +1 For also showing how to extract the number, though I guess the OP only wanted "yes" or "no" in this case. ;-)